# Postfix relay gives error 450 while it should be 550

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

we use postfix to do relaying.

We get several messages like the following in /var/log/mail (slightly edited)

```
Apr 13 13:30:29 linserver postfix/smtpd[1064]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[$ip]:     450 4.1.1 <0827523@domain.be>: Recipient address rejected: undeliverable address: host domain.be [$ip] said: 550 <0827523@domain.be>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table (in reply to RCPT TO command); from=<beststore@yahoo.com> to=<0827523@domain.be> proto=ESMTP helo=<BLUESTREAK.domain.local>
```

Now, when the master mail servers gives a 550, claiming that the user does not exist, I want the relay to also give a 550 back.  What happens now is that it seems to return a 450, causing clients to keep messages queued, keep trying and only notify users after a certain period has passed.

According to what I could find, the soft_bounce could cause this.
But we have not enabled this option (and by default it's off according to postfix docs)
It might also have something to do with the `*_reject_code postconf` values. Especially since the log message complains the unknown ip.  But as you can see in the postconf  output below, `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and `smtpd_client_restrictions` are empty.
So even *if* it would try to do any restrictions there, 550 is the "worst" error going on, so that's what I expect to be returned to the client.

- postconf: http://sprunge.us/JYgB

Thanks,

Dieter

Answer (score 1):

Add/Change "unknown_address_reject_code = 550" in Postfix conf file and try.

Comment: According to the docs, that setting is a parameter which affects reject_unknown_sender_domain and reject_unknown_recipient_domain behavior.
However, I have no `reject_unknown_sender_domain` in my config.
I do have the `reject_unknown_recipient_domain` recepient restriction, but the docs say "Reject the request when the recipient mail address has no DNS A or MX record"
this is not the case. the domain has an A record.

Answer (score 0):

I set unverified_recipient_reject_code to 550 and that seems to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you set `soft_bounce = yes`, all errors will be turned into 450 soft bounds errors so that the emitter retries sending the mail after some time.

This is convenient as debugging precaution when configuring Postfix so that a configuration error doesn't result in unrecoverable loss of mails.